# Change drawing Scale on AutoCAD

Tags: vba, autocad

Hi I'm working on a code that will convert imperial values to metric. But I'm having trouble getting my code to work, it always gives me an error on the first line. See code below:

```
Sub DrawingViewScale()
    Dim oDoc As DrawingDocument
    Set oDoc = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument

    Dim oView As DrawingView
    Set oView = oDoc.ActiveSheet.DrawingViews.Item(1)
    MsgBox oView.scale()

    oView.[scale] = 25.4
    MsgBox oView.scale()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare oDoc like this

```
Dim oDoc As AcadDocument
```

That is the answer for question about

> error on the first line

But in this code are many more problems

Comment: It worked, thanks but now the error has been moved to the 3rd line now. I just want a code that will automatically change an imperial to metric drawing scale.

Comment: Can You see any similarity between first and third lines?
You have error? realy? maybe You share error message?

Comment: So it means Your declaration is wrong. I think You should use Object  Browser (F2) to find correct data types in CAD Application.
By the way it seems to be a misunderstinding. You mentioned about "convert" but manipulate only view. Your code, even when will be correct will zoom the view but not change any dimension of any entity

Comment: I'm still new to vba, it can get confusing at times, but thanks